# How to display Web Service Data in a table on a HTML Webpage?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, web-services

I want to display some information in my website from a web-service. The web-service return values in .json format. I dont want to use any server side languages as my website is Static one. How could I display the .json data in the web page in a table with the help of JQuery or AngularJS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Jquery

You can use an ajax request or `$.getJSON` method to get data from server and parse that json and add that to your table.

```
    $.ajax ({
     url :'www.google.com',
     type:'GET',
     datatype: 'json',
     success:function(data) {
        var tr
        for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
        tr = $('<tr />')
        tr.append("<td>" + data.name +"</td">);
        tr.append("<td"> + data.phone + "</td">);
        $("table").append(tr);
    }
 })

$.getJSON method is smaller and use can parse the data using `$.each`

 $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    $.each(json, function(item){
    $("td").append(item);
    });
});
```

Just modify your append structure according to your table and your json data.

## AngularJS

#### For Angular 1.x version

you can use **$http** method

```
  $http({
    url :'https://www.yourUrlHere/api/json',
    method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function success(response){
    $scope.data = response;
     },function error(response) {
    $scope.error = response;
    })
});


Then in your table structure you can use ng-repeat to loop through the data and add that data into your table.


<table>
<tr ng-repeat="values in data">
<td>{{values.name}}</td>
<td>{{values.phone}}</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

You have to modify the response json according to your need. For example, if user info in stored in response.users, then you need to set $scope.data = response.users